# MATLAB Pid function is not found

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have a MATLAB 2009b for Mac, and when I use pid function MATLAB print out:

```
??? Undefined function or variable 'pid'.
```

Comment: Is the control systems toolbox installed?

Comment: If you do `help pid` and there nothing, that mean the toolbox isn't installed.

Comment: @user2987828 I'm pretty sure that the OP refers to a PID controller (Proportional, Integral, Derivative) as opposed to a pid as a process identifier. The `pid` function is part of the Control Systems Toolbox: http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/control/ref/pid.html.

Comment: Try `which -all pid` and that should tell you 1) if the Control Systems Toolbox is installed and 2) if it's licensed